# Can't make correct GraphQL query to Yelp

Tags: reactjs, api, graphql, apollo, yelp

Maybe this thing is obvious but I'm new to Apollo.
I'm trying to send a simple graphQL query to yelp server

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { yelpCredentials } from '../../../keys/yelp/config';
import 'cross-fetch/polyfill';
import App from './components/App';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/graphql',
});
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = yelpCredentials.API_Key;
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
      'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
    },
  };
});
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

client.query(
 ***[QUERY_CONTENT]***
 ,
}).then(console.log);

render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

tried:
query1:

```
client.query({
  query: gql`
  query business($id: String!) {
      business(id: $id) {
        name
        id
        alias
        rating
        url
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: { id: 'garaje-san-francisco' },
}).then(console.log);
```

error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

query2:

```
client.query({
  query: gql`
      query business(id: "garaje-san-francisco") {
        name
        id
        alias
        rating
        url
      }
    }
  `,
}).then(console.log);
```

error: "Syntax Error: Expected $, found Name "id""

query3:

```
 client.query({
  query: gql`
    query business($id: String!) {
      name
      id
      alias
      rating
      url
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    id: 'garaje-san-francisco',
  },
}).then(console.log);
```

error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I'm getting data with postman https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc3uE.jpg

Comment: Are you using 'Content-Type': 'application/json' -header in your request?

Comment: There might be some problem with authentication, thats why yelp might return you HTML instead of JSON and Apollo cannot parse it. Have you tried to `console.log`  object that you return from `setContext`, does it looks good?

Answer (score 0):

import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';

I was trying to apply configuration for apollo-client client to apollo-boost client